# Windows backup to network share

Tags: linux, windows, backup

I'm looking for an incremental backup service for Windows.

I really liked Crashplan, and this is almost exactly what I'm looking for, but I need something that can backup to a samba share or ftp or something like that. Crashplan can only backup to other computers running Crashplan, Crashplan's cloud service, or another hard drive on the local machine.

This backup "server" is a Raspberry Pi.

Preferably free or open source solutions.

Comment: file level backups or system level backups?

Comment: file level. It's really just for important documents and photographs that I can restore in the event of a rm -f type event or grab the drive and run in the event of apocalypse

Answer (score 1):

If its file level backups, I use [bitorrent sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html). You install a client on either end (the Arm version runs on a pi, with a webui), generate a synchronization key and a path to backup (which can be one way or two ways) and copy the key over to the machine you want to sync to, and set a save location. Then it handles backups automatically with no intervention.

You want the linux ARM varient on your raspberry pi

[image]

Download, and uncompress it, then run ./btsync - you can access the webui at :8888 - and set a username and password from the preferences -> authorization menu.

Likewise, install the client on windows.

I'm not sure how it handles large files that are partially changed, but its pretty fast, and efficient in general.